MAUI 8.0 app suddenly does not compile anymore: access denied on image in Resizetizer
Suddenly my MAUI Android / iOS 8.0 app does not compile anymore. I'm stuck on an exception
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      Access to the path 'C:\...\obj\Debug\net8.0-android\resizetizer\r\drawable\....png' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.OpenFile(String path, FileAccess access, SafeFileHandle& handle)
   at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path, DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.ResizetizeImages.ExecuteAsync() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\ResizetizeImages.cs:line 105
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() MercatorPenguinMaui (net8.0-android)    C:\Nugets\microsoft.maui.resizetizer\8.0.40\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.After.targets    631

The png file name on the second line changes randomly.
I've tried :

Delete bin and obj folders (multiple times)
Reboot PC
Delete all nugets in nugets cache directory (and reboot PC)
Double check that no picture files with the same name exist in different places of the projects (name without extension)
Run Visual Studio as admin

The same source code compiles correctly on another computer.
The same problem is encountered on other unchanged projects which previously compiled perfectly.
Visual Studio used is 17.10.3.

What is the path to your project root folder?

Sometimes the problem may arise if the path is too long, try to place project folder to your Documents folder, then clear bin/obj files and try to compile.

" previously compiled perfectly" means that something changed on the tooling or dependencies, VS, MAUI or a package.

Visual Studio has been updated from 17.10.2 to 17.10.3 but after the problem was encountered. The path length to the solution is 58. When moving this project to other directories for testing, I fear I have understood that it is the TFS readonly flag which is causing the problem. As I check out for edit the Resources\Images folder, the compilation occurs correctly.

Seems you have solved your question. Feel free to post an answer which may help others with similar question.

According to opened issues describing a similar problem:

MAUI - Resizetizer files access to the path is denied
[BUG] Resizetizer file access issues on Windows build in Visual Studio in CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.2.2

It is a bug and as a workaround revert to below package versions:

CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0.0
CommunityToolkit.Maui 8.0.1


Whenever you say something similar to "previously compiled perfectly" while nothing changed in your code, then investigate the tooling or dependencies; VS, workload (MAUI) or a package.

CommunityToolkit.Mvvm is not used. CommunityToolkit.Maui used is 8.0.1

ave you recently updated VS or MAUI or a any nuget package ?

Visual Studio has been updated from 17.10.2 to 17.10.3 but after the problem was encountered. No nuget update.
