Access is Denied from Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer
I have been working on a port from .NET Xamarin to .NET MAUI with .NET 8
With much pain, I've been making progress (Maui is VERY buggy and quirky).
All of a sudden my builds fail with this error:
Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.After.targets(631,9): error MAUI0000: There was an exception processing the image 'E:{project path}\Resources\Images\someimage.png': System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '{projectpath}\obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\resizetizer\r\drawable\red.png' is denied.
(I think the ONLY thing I did prior to this was to attempt to change the Android target framework, but then I set it back)
I've tried deleting all my output folders (bin, obj), cleaning, rebuilding, cleaning the nuget packages and restoring, rebooting VS, rebooting the machine... nothing works.
Has anyone else encountered this?  Any solutions?
I'm running Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.10.4
Build is for .NET MAUI, Android platform (only), .NET 8, Android SDK Level 34

Similar as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78673435/maui-8-0-app-suddenly-does-not-compile-anymore-access-denied-on-image-in-resize Please consider my comment about readonly state of those files set by TFS.

1, Close Visual Studio,. 2. Delete all bin and obj folders in your solution. 3. Launch VS and try to build again.

I don't know if this is an actual "solution" or if some other buggy magic caused things to start working again, but:  I opened a command prompt, went into ~Resources/Images and removed the read only flag on all files.  Then the solution built.   Very weird behavior.  This should make NO difference for the build.

You can try to delete the file and add it again. And don't forget to set its build action as MauiImage.

FYI: I seemed to have worked my way out of this by removing the read only flag on ALL of the image files under my Resources folder.
